# need to trim first 11 characters off a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway to trim the first x amount of characters in a varchar? I am unable to do this using the left or right functions a well as other trimming methods. Will be doing this on standard MS-SQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT STUFF(SomeString,1,11,'')
```

([obligatory link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188043%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing it. One of the simpler ones would be to use [`RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) and [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) combination:

```
select RIGHT(a.col, LEN(a.col)-11) from MyTable a
```

Comment: any other suggestions? I keep getting an "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function." when I try to run this, if it helps, my column name is title and the table name is @temp

Comment: @njj56 This is because your string is shorter than 11. But Martin's answer is better anyway :)